# Redrawing Canvas in Android custom View

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to set up a canvas to redraw whenever the user clicks a button. Whenever I trigger the redraw via invalidate() the app freezes and crashes. I am very new to android development so I am struggling to see what I neglecting. Any insight would be appriciated.

The relevent classes are included below.

Thanks,

mainactivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun submit(view: View) {
        val text = findViewById<View>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal) as EditText
        val canvas = findViewById<View>(R.id.customCanvas) as CustomCanvas
        val value = text.text.toString()

        val t = findViewById<View>(R.id.textView) as TextView
        t.text = value
        canvas.setWeightandRedraw(value.toFloat())
    }

}
```

canvas

```
class CustomCanvas : View {
    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    }
    var weight: Float = 0.0f;

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        drawBar(canvas);
        drawWeightKg(canvas, this.weight)
    }

    fun setWeightandRedraw(_weight: Float) {
        weight = _weight;
        invalidate();
    }

    fun drawBar(canvas: Canvas?) {
    .........
    }

    fun drawWeightKg(canvas: Canvas?, weight: Float) {
    .........
    }
}
```

Comment: post stacktrace.

Comment: Stacktrace Posted

Comment: Edit removed the stack trace as the one I posted was for a different issue

Comment: I am seeing 'Wrote stack traces to tombstoned' but I cannot seem to find 'tombstoned' anywhere...

Comment: The stack trace will be in logcat when it crashes. And I'm anticipating you're going to need to show all your code in the CustomCanvas class.

Answer (score -1):

Moving invalidate() to onDraw() appeard to fix this.

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    drawBar(canvas);
    drawWeightKg(canvas, this.weight)
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: This will force a redraw every frame, which I'm guessing you don't want